# Nuget packages and their dependency trees

Tags: dependencies, nuget

Say I am building a Nuget package, MyNuget.  It has a dependency on NugetA, which has a dependency on NugetB.  But I want to replace the implementation contained in NugetB with an implementation in NugetBAlternative.

Can I set up MyNuget so that when my client downloads it, NugetB is not downloaded?

- **MyNuget**  *when the client downloads this*

  - **NugetA** *this is downloaded*

    - **NugetB** *this is not downloaded*
  - **NugetBAlternative** *this is downloaded to replace NugetB*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet is not designed to do work like that.

If all the NuGet packages are on NuGet.org then what you are describing will not work.

To get this to work you will have to work against NuGet or maybe you should just include the binaries from NuGetA in your NuGet package instead.

One way would be to not use the official NuGet.org then you could have your own version of NuGetB which is different to the official one. However you could only use your own NuGet package source to get this to work.

Comment: This gives me a sad.  I really don't like NugetB, and I'd prefer not to have my clients download it, if possible.